# How to record the path in this critical path algo (Python - Floyd Warshall)

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I'm writing a code to find the shortest path between all pairs in a "n x n" matrix. So my code seems to be working and returning the shortest path. But now I'd like to record the path between the vertices, not just the shortest distance. Example - the shortest path between cities 1 and 44 resulted in 5 days. Now I'd like to know the path it took, which in the example would be 1 --> 5 --> 12 --> 44.

```
# The number of vertices
nV = len(G)-1
print(range(nV))
INF = 999

# Algorithm implementation
def floyd_warshall(G):
    distance = list(map(lambda i: list(map(lambda j: j, i)), G))

    # Adding vertices individually
    for k in range(nV):
        for i in range(nV):
            for j in range(nV):
                distance[i][j] = min(distance[i][j], distance[i][k] + distance[k][j])
    print_solution(distance)


cobalt = list(map(lambda i: list(map(lambda j: j, i)), G))

# Printing the solution
def print_solution(distance):
    for i in range(nV):
        for j in range(nV):
            if(distance[i][j] == INF):
                print("INF", end=" ")
            else:
                print(distance[i][j], end="  ")
            cobalt[i][j] = distance[i][j]            
        print(" ")


abcd = np.asarray(cobalt)
np.savetxt("foo.csv", abcd, delimiter=",")

floyd_warshall(G)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a modification to Floyd-Warshall algorithm:
Keep a pair `(distance, k)`, where `k` is the intermediate vertex that updated distance value, instead of only the distance. Default value for `k` is `-1`.

```py
if distance[i][j][0] > distance[i][k][0] + distance[k][j][0]:
    distance[i][j] = (distance[i][k][0] + distance[k][j][0], k)
```

You can reconstruct any shortest path by recursion.

```py
def get_path(i, j):
    if distance[i][j] == +oo: # oo stand for infinite
        return []             # None is also an option
    k = distance[i][j][1]
    if k == -1:
        return [i, j]
    else:
        path = get_path(i, k)
        path.pop()            # remove k to avoid duplicates
        path.extend(get_path(k, j))
        return path
```

Runtime: `O(length of path)`

Note: A requirement to obtain a minimum cost path from `x` to `y` is that there aren't negative cost cycles between any path from `x` to `y`.

Comment: Hi @Eloy. I would add this get path to the existing code with no changes? Furthermore, and this may be a stupid question, what is the reason for having a [0] in red in the first set of code?

Comment: You need to modify floyd_warshall method so it can calculate both cost of minimum cost path and intermediate vertex used to achieve that minimum cost (needed to recover a minimum cost path). The required modification is mentioned above, in answer's first code cell. The [0] is where current minimum cost is stored and [1] is where intermediate vertex is stored. It's explained at first paragraph.

Comment: Now it's clear to me, thanks for the explanation Eloy. Cheers, have a good weekend.

Comment: Eloy - I keep getting this error. Where would I need to adjust my code?


```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
string index out of range
  File "C:\Users\marcelo.novaes\Desktop\floydwarshall\floydwarshall_run2.py", line 30, in get_path
    k = distance[i][j][1]
  File "C:\Users\marcelo.novaes\Desktop\floydwarshall\floydwarshall_run2.py", line 50, in floyd_warshall
    get_path(i, j)
  File "C:\Users\marcelo.novaes\Desktop\floydwarshall\floydwarshall_run2.py", line 60, in <module>
    floyd_warshall(G)
```

Comment: @mcnovaes Possible errors: i or j are the index out of range (check if every use of get_path garantees that input parameters are in the correct range 0 <= i, j < n), [1] is causing the problem (then you need to review the code where you create distance array so its 3rd dimension has size two). Also, i recommend you to do some debugging. You can use your favorite debugging tool or just to use a few prints to find out the real issue.